# Invalid opcode when storing value in array part of a mapped struct

Tags: solidity, storage, opcode

I have a public function that accepts some data from users and i basically want to store this data into a struct that is mapped to an address.

This is the definition of the Struct :

```
struct APINodeJobResponse {
        uint256 jobId;
        uint256[] responseValue;
    }
```

This is the definition of the mapping :

```
mapping(address => APINodeJobResponse) public jobResponses;
```

This is the function that fails to execute :

```
function receiveRevealedAPIJobResult(
        uint256[] memory dataValues,
        uint256 rand,
        uint256 jobId
    ) public {
        //fetch committment string to ensure no tampering
            APINodeJobResponse memory newJobResponse;
            newJobResponse.jobId = jobId;
            for (uint i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
               newJobResponse.responseValue[i]= dataValues[i];
           }
            jobResponses[msg.sender] = newJobResponse;
    }
```

I've been at this for more than 6 hours. Scoured the web trying to figure out what is happening and ran into numerous (Out of gas) exceptions. When I got out of gas exceptions my thought went to that i cant save dynamic data onto a storage variable since EVM cannot know before hand the size of the data.

Now I have no idea what the problem is but it seems to have a problem with the saving part (to the storage variable)

This is the error :

```
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode
    at Object.ErrorResponse (/Users/moustafa/Documents/veritas/veritas/oracleNodeNetwork/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/node_modules/web3-core-helpers/lib/errors.js:28:19)
    at Object.callback (/Users/moustafa/Documents/veritas/veritas/oracleNodeNetwork/node_modules/web3-core-requestmanager/lib/index.js:302:36)
    at /Users/moustafa/Documents/veritas/veritas/oracleNodeNetwork/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:114:45
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at WebsocketProvider._onMessage (/Users/moustafa/Documents/veritas/veritas/oracleNodeNetwork/node_modules/web3-providers-ws/lib/index.js:102:69)
    at W3CWebSocket._dispatchEvent [as dispatchEvent] (/Users/moustafa/Documents/veritas/veritas/oracleNodeNetwork/node_modules/yaeti/lib/EventTarget.js:115:12)
    at W3CWebSocket.onMessage (/Users/moustafa/Documents/veritas/veritas/oracleNodeNetwork/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:234:14)
    at WebSocketConnection.<anonymous> (/Users/moustafa/Documents/veritas/veritas/oracleNodeNetwork/node_modules/websocket/lib/W3CWebSocket.js:205:19)
    at WebSocketConnection.emit (node:events:390:28)
    at WebSocketConnection.processFrame (/Users/moustafa/Documents/veritas/veritas/oracleNodeNetwork/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:554:26)
    at /Users/moustafa/Documents/veritas/veritas/oracleNodeNetwork/node_modules/websocket/lib/WebSocketConnection.js:323:40
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:78:11) {
  data: {
    '0x5a54387c1a44c929ceaf2060539e2c54b5e9435b29f7138a794a22c6a705bf86': { error: 'invalid opcode', program_counter: 2460, return: '0x' },
    stack: 'RuntimeError: VM Exception while processing transaction: invalid opcode\n' +
      '    at Function.RuntimeError.fromResults (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/utils/runtimeerror.js:94:13)\n' +
      '    at BlockchainDouble.processBlock (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/blockchain_double.js:627:24)\n' +
      '    at runMicrotasks (<anonymous>)\n' +
      '    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)',
    name: 'RuntimeError'
  }
}
```

I get this error from the js client (user) script that is trying to call this function.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

The array within your struct is in memory, you first need to initialise it (with a given length, to allocate the appropriate space) - see https://docs.soliditylang.org/en/latest/types.html#allocating-memory-arrays

This code doesn't revert (notice the `newJobResponse.responseValue = new uint[](dataValues.length);`)

```
function receiveRevealedAPIJobResult(
        uint256[] memory dataValues,
        uint256 rand,
        uint256 jobId
    ) public {
        //fetch committment string to ensure no tampering
            APINodeJobResponse memory newJobResponse;
            newJobResponse.jobId = jobId;
            newJobResponse.responseValue = new uint256[](dataValues.length);
            for (uint i = 0; i < dataValues.length; i++) {
               newJobResponse.responseValue[i]= dataValues[i];
           }
            jobResponses[msg.sender] = newJobResponse;
    }
```

Comment: I tried this before, and I get an OUT OF GAS error :( 

` 
Error: Returned error: VM Exception while processing transaction: out of gas
`

Comment: How long was the array and how much did you use? I tried my solution in Remix without revert